# Oracle SQL - max of avg function

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a table dane2_:

```
day          |visitors_number
-------------|---------------
02/01/2020   |250
...
```

Instructions:
1. Average number of visitors on individual days of the week (record the day of the week as text: Monday,
Tuesday etc.). 
I did:

```
SELECT 
day_written, ROUND( AVG (visitors_number),0) AS avg_visitors_number FROM
(SELECT day, TO_CHAR(day,'DAY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = POLISH') AS day_written,
visitors_number
FROM dane2_) 
GROUP BY day_written
ORDER BY avg_visitors_number DESC;
```

2. On what day of the week is the average number of visitors the highest?
   I would like to use the previous query, but not write it back. The code should be as simple as possible, using MAX funtion. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "but not write it back"? As is, you could just add `FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES` at the end of your query to get the day(s) with the maximum average number of visitors.

Comment: I would like to use MAX function instead of FETCH.

Comment: You want it more complicated? Okay :-) The simplest would then be `MAX OVER` on your average values. And if you don't want to use a window function either, then you'd use your query twice (as main query and subquery), which would best be written with a `WITH` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is one where you could just use `ROWNUM` in an outer query.  Take a look at this example:

```sql
SELECT sub.day_of_week, 
       ROUND(sub.avg_visitors_number, 0) AS AVG_VISITORS_NUMBER
FROM (SELECT TO_CHAR(d.day, 'DAY') AS DAY_OF_WEEK, 
             AVG(d.visitors_number) AS AVG_VISITORS_NUMBER
      FROM dane2 d
      GROUP BY TO_CHAR(d.day, 'DAY')
      ORDER BY AVG_VISITORS_NUMBER DESC) sub
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Here is a DBFiddle with this example ([Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=22e7b04793e86845e4bfcd1d3c34f719))

The query takes your ordered results and just selects the first row. The one note is that I recommend doing the round after the sort to allow you to get the most accurate results.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options.

Sample data first:

```
SQL> create table dane2_ as
  2    (select trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + level - 1 day,
  3            round(dbms_random.value(1, 10)) visitors_number
  4     from dual
  5     connect by level <= 14
  6    );

Table created.

SQL> select * From dane2_ order by day;

DAY        VISITORS_NUMBER
---------- ---------------
01.04.2020               9
02.04.2020               5
03.04.2020               8
04.04.2020               1
05.04.2020               6
06.04.2020               1
07.04.2020               9
08.04.2020               9
09.04.2020               5
10.04.2020               4
11.04.2020               7
12.04.2020               6
13.04.2020               4
14.04.2020               5

14 rows selected.
```

---

Averages per days (English names; my output doesn't *speak* Polish nicely):

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select day,
  3       to_char(day, 'FMDay', 'nls_date_language=english') as day_written,
  4       visitors_number
  5     from dane2_
  6    )
  7  select day_written,
  8    round(avg(visitors_number)) as avg_visitors_number
  9  from temp
 10  group by day_written
 11  order by avg_visitors_number;

DAY_WRITTEN                          AVG_VISITORS_NUMBER
------------------------------------ -------------------
Monday                                                 3
Saturday                                               4
Thursday                                               5
Friday                                                 6
Sunday                                                 6
Tuesday                                                7
Wednesday                                              9      --> highest number

7 rows selected.
```

---

Option you wanted to use (with `MAX` function):

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select day,
  3       to_char(day, 'FMDay', 'nls_date_language=english') as day_written,
  4       visitors_number
  5     from dane2_
  6    ),
  7  avgs as
  8    (select day_written,
  9       round(avg(visitors_number)) as avg_visitors_number
 10     from temp
 11     group by day_written
 12    )
 13  select a.day_written
 14  from avgs a
 15  where a.avg_visitors_number = (select max(b.avg_visitors_number)
 16                                 from avgs b
 17                                );

DAY_WRITTEN
------------------------------------
Wednesday
```

---

Or, you could *rank* them in descending order and fetch the first one:

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select day,
  3       to_char(day, 'FMDay', 'nls_date_language=english') as day_written,
  4       visitors_number
  5     from dane2_
  6    ),
  7  avgs as
  8    (select day_written,
  9       round(avg(visitors_number)) as avg_visitors_number,
 10       rank() over (order by round(avg(visitors_number)) desc) rnk
 11     from temp
 12     group by day_written
 13    )
 14  select day_written
 15  from avgs
 16  where rnk = 1;

DAY_WRITTEN
------------------------------------
Wednesday

SQL>
```